# Passing a user defined method to the constructor

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I want to create a simple input dialog. so I added a Windows From to my application and in that window I've put a label, a textbox and a button; For now it's easy to fill the required proprieties of my controls with the predefined values using constructors and return the entered value with `result`;

```
public partial class GeneralInputForm : Form
{
    public string result = "";
    public GeneralInputForm(string label, string defaultValue = "")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = label;
        textBox1.Text = defaultValue;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = textBox1.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

And now creating an instance of the from and filling the parameters with the required values;

```
GeneralInputForm formInput = new GeneralInputForm("Please enter your age:");
formInput.ShowDialog();

//formInput.result      holds the value
```

My questions raises here; What if I want to check for the validity of the value that the user has entered in the textbox in the GeneralInputForm itself (and not later when instantiating the form with checking the `result` field)? I mean is there such a functionality in C# (delegates maybe) so that the user himself can define a method and pass a it as one of the parameters of the constructor which that method checks the `textbox1.text` value to be sure that for example it's successfully can be parsed into an `int` or `float` or `string`?

I don't want to add an ugly string parameter called `variableType` to my constructor and ask user to say if he requires a 'int' or 'float' or 'string' or  whatever and then I myself by checking the value of `variableType`, wrote different statements for making sure that the entered text can be successfully parsed into int or float or string (it would be an ugly and limited solution)

Comment: Since you've already considered delegates as an option, why didn't you end up using them?

Comment: I have not understood if you expect the called form to perform any conversion or not. It seems that you don't ask this job to be executed by the called form but you want a delegate that the GenericInputForm calls back to check for the input validity. Am I wrong?

Comment: You got your answer, but you didn't give feedback.

Comment: The problem is if using delegates would be the answer, I don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the answers; I ended up to this simple and clear solution using delegates;

```
public partial class SimpleInputForm : Form
{
    public string Value = "";
    public delegate bool VerifyDel(string input);
    private VerifyDel Methods;
    public SimpleInputForm(string lable, VerifyDel method)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = lable;
        Methods = new VerifyDel(method);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Methods(textBox1.Text))
        {
            Value = textBox1.Text;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and now I show the form with user defined functionality for the evaluation of input;

```
SimpleInputForm simpleInput = new SimpleInputForm("Enter your age:", (input => {
    try
    {
        int age = int.Parse(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid value for age!");
        return false;
    }
}));

//simpleInput.Value     holds the input value
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `GeneralInputForm` to `GeneralInputForm<T>`.  Is a generic class, just like `List<String>`.

You can use two field Func one to cast the Text to the object you want and one to check the return just like this:

```
public partial class GeneralInputForm<T> : Form
{
    public T result = default(T);
    Func<T, Boolean> check = (input) => true; // Default check
    Func<String, T> cast = null; // Default cast

    public GeneralInputForm(string label, string defaultValue = "", Func<String, T> cast, Func<T, Boolean> check)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = label;
        textBox1.Text = defaultValue;
        if(check != null)
            this.check = check;
        this.cast = cast;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cast != null)
        {
            T casted = cast(textBox1.Text);

            if(casted != null && check(casted)){
                result = textBox1.Text;
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Func<String, int> cast = (input) => int.Parse(input);
Func<int, Boolean> check = (input) => input > 0;
GeneralInputForm<int> form = new GeneralInputForm<int>("Enter a number:", "1", cast, check);
form.ShowDialog();
//etc....
```

[More info about Generics.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zHRmXkJ5Bw)

This way of doing thing is named Dependecy Injection, and this approach is the constructor injection type. [More info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: for this line: 
public T result = "";
I got this error: cannot implicitly convert type string to T

Comment: Your're right, copy-paste errors you know... Updated.

Comment: While the idea is nice (and it'd work), I'd avoid having generic types for forms unless strictly necessary, specially if you would ever want to inherit from them

Comment: So we need just to remove cast from the ecuation and do the cast in the check. But the cast and the Dependency Injection is precisely to avoid the inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it as a parameter. The validation function can be overridden using inheritance.

```
  public partial class GeneralInputForm : Form
  {
      // Returns true if this text is valid for a textbox
      protected virtual bool IsValid(string text)
      {
          return true;                    // default behaviour
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (IsValid(textBox1.Text))
          {
              result = textBox1.Text;     // ok
              Close();
          }
          else
          {
              // Show error message
          }
      }
  }
```

Now you can create a form which custom-validates textboxes, by overriding (ie. replacing) the IsValid() function:

```
  public partial class SpecificInputForm : GeneralInputForm
  {
       // Blank textboxes are not valid, and are restricted to 31 characters
       protected override bool IsValid(string text)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(text))
               return false;

           return (text.Length < 32);
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Oscar's answer would work, making forms generic is a bit of a bad idea because the Winforms designer has aversion to them (try to inherit from that form and you'll see).

I'd probably make it so that it's not the form that is generic, but a method:

```
public partial class GeneralInputForm : Form
{
  private GeneralInputForm() // Private constructor
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public static bool TryGetValue<T>(
             string label, 
             string defaultValue, 
             Func<T, bool> check, 
             out T result
         ) where T : IConvertible
  {
    result = default(T);
    using (var frm = new GeneralInputForm())
    {
      frm.label1.Text = label;
      frm.textBox1.Text = defaultValue;
      frm.Closing += (o, e) =>
      {
        var myForm = (GeneralInputForm) o;
        // User closed not clicking the button?
        if (myForm.DialogResult != DialogResult.OK) 
          return;
        try
        {
          var checkval = (T) Convert.ChangeType(myForm.textBox1.Text, typeof (T));
          if (!check(checkval))
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        catch
        {
          e.Cancel = true;
        }

      };
      if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(frm.textBox1.Text, typeof (T));
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Don't use `Close()` on modal forms, it's always better to 
    // return a dialog result. This will close the form aswell
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 

  }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
int result;
if(GeneralInputForm.TryGetValue("Enter an integer over 10", 
                                "10", 
                                (x) => x > 10, 
                                out result))
  MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
else
  /* User closed the form by other means */
```

Or:

```
string result;
if (GeneralInputForm.TryGetValue("Enter \"Hello\"",
                                 "Goodbye", 
                                 (x) => x == "Hello", 
                                 out result))
```

This will not let you close the form by clicking `button1` unless the value is correct, but will let you close it by other means (alt+f4, clicking the `x`, etc.). It'll return `true` if it was closed by the button, or `false` if it wasn't (you can put a `Cancel` button there).

You could also make the `defaultValue` parameter be of type `T` and assign `defaultValue.ToString()` to the textbox

A messagebox can be shown to the user in the `Closing` delegate if the value is not valid, or you can make your own logic

This requires that `T` is `IConvertible`, but about any type having a `Parse` method is

Comment: While the designer won't work with a derived class of a Generic form, the Dependency Injection way allow you to avoid the inheritance as you can give the form all the functionalities you want.